# How to use a custom font in react native with nativewind?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie in React-Native and I have an issue with fonts adding, I'm trying to load a custom font from .otf file, but I have an error:

```
fontFamily "Pixel-Musketeer" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
```

I have tried to use the Font.loadAsync but get this error in any case.

My code right now:

### Home.js

```js
import {
  View,
  Text
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";

// State
import {
  useState
} from "react";

// Fonts
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import useFonts from "../hooks/useFonts";

const Home = () => {
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async() => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady)
    return ( <
      AppLoading startAsync = {
        LoadFonts
      }
      onFinish = {
        () => SetIsReady(true)
      }
      onError = {
        () => {}
      } >
      < /AppLoading>
    );

  return ( <
    View className = "bg-mainRed flex-1 justify-center items-center" >
    <
    Text className = "font-Musketeer text-5xl" > King 's Dungeon</Text> <
    /View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

### useFonts.js

```js
import * as Font from "expo-font";

export default useFonts = async () =>
  await Font.loadAsync({
    Musketeer: require("../assets/fonts/Pixel-Musketeer.otf"),
  });
```

### Tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./screens/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      mainRed: "#3B111D",
      grey: "#564950",
      darkGreen: "#86978F",
      green: "#BEDDA4",
      brightGreen: "#E4FABD",
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        Musketeer: ["Pixel-Musketeer"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

What should I remove or add in order to load this font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use/make theme.js where you save as constants so that you can use it on whole app:

```
export const FONTFAMILY = {
    musketeer: {fontFamily: 'Musketeer'},
}
```

and then in you main App.js

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { FONTFAMILY } from './theme.js';

export default function App() {

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Musketeer': require("../assets/fonts/Pixel-Musketeer.otf"),
  });

  if(!fontsLoaded) return null;

  return (
    <Text style={{...FONTFAMILY.musketeer}}>used fonts here</Text
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

define your font name and file in the tailwind.config.js file, like so

```
module.exports = { fontFamily: {fontName: "fontFileName"} }
```

and put this font file (.otf or .ttf) in your `./assets/fonts/` folder.

install the "expo-font" package and import it into your `App.js` file.

Now load the fonts in your App component before the return, like so:

```
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";

export default function App() {
...
// Loading font
fonts const [loaded] = useFonts({
    fontFileName: require("./assets/fonts/fontFileName.otf")
});

if (!loaded) {
return null;
}
// Your App component JSX
return (
    ...
)
}
```

Then use the in your classes:

```
className="font-fontName"
```

If you run into naming issues, se this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59943383/7925161).

Comment: What if I dont use expo? When I type as font-[font name] it works but its not working with the name I gave in tailwind.config

Answer (score -1):

If not already created, create a config file at the root of the project named react-native.config.js. Proceed by adding the following code inside module.exports:

Comment: What a code????